# Excel to sum value of duplicates while retaining its duplicate text

Tags: excel, duplicates

I need help on a loooong list of values that is possibly having duplicates with its quantity needed to sum however while retaining its duplicates.
Hard to explain, example of scenario and goal I'd like to achieve. 
Please help.

**Current Situation**
material value

a        10

b        10

a        10

c        10

c        10

a        10

b        10

b        10

b        10

**Goal to Achieve**
material value

a        30

b        40

a        30

c        20

c        20

a        30

b        40

b        40

b        40

Something like above. I'm jumbled up with the formulas. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important point to consider here: First, because you need to sum values AND change the values you're summing, you're going to get a circular reference if you try to do this dynamically.

One way to get around this is to add a third column, with the formula `=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)`

If you absolutely need the values in column B, just copy from C, then paste the values, or just hide column B.

Comment: yes, finally got it! thanks alot... saved me with more then 12k rows zzz. thank you!